# upgraded to xcode 4.2 now there is no animation on presentViewController and dismissViewController

Tags: objective-c, modalviewcontroller, ios5

I use an app with horizontal scrollview and paging. Some of my pages have flip sides.
After upgrading to XCode 4.2 and IOS 5 everything still works fine except for one thing.

The modalTransitionStyle animation only works on the first page. On all other pages the parent view disappears and some small time later the flip side appears. Between these to views, the screen is blank.

When I build the app for IOS 4.3, then the animation is visible again.

Any suggestions why on IOS 5 the animation isn´t visible?